# Is there any way I can find an Element by RGB Color? (WebDriver, C#)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

In order to make my program work, I need to find a unique element(s) that are a certain RGB color. Basically, I'm trying to see if there is a way I can possibly find all the elements on the page, find the element(s) that are of this certain RGB color and save their coordinates to a variable.

Is this possible and, if so, how would I go about doing this?

Sample Code:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Successfully found question set.");
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    go:
    try
    {
        if (!rage)
        {
            Random interval = new Random();
            int waitTime = interval.Next(1000, 10000);
            Thread.Sleep(waitTime);
        }
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnCheckAnswer")).Click();
        //Insert font finding and coordinate saving here.
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("bNext.Image")).Click();
        goto go;
    } //Omitted the "Catch" section as it is unneccessary here.
```

HTML Sample: http://pastebin.com/Y6Ye6Cqu

Thank you,

MTS11648

Comment: Are all the ekements the same type?

Comment: What do you mean by "element"? Typically there are images composed of many pixels, and each pixel is an RGB color. Are you talking about checking each pixel in every image?

Comment: @JohnSchultz Yes, they are all text.

Comment: @J.McCabe Not images, just text primarily. Basically, there is a "Check" function on this website and it will highlight the text with the specific RGB color I mentioned. I'm looking to find the text with that color and save its coordinates.

Comment: If the elements are the same color, shouldn't they have the same CSS class? I don't know of any way to get elements by color other than walking the entire DOM, which is a terrible approach.

Comment: @DanWilson The elements do have the same CSS class, but the problem is there are elements in the same class with a different font color, so I don't know how I'd distinguish them from each other.

Comment: Well then it sounds like you should restructure your classes so that you know the font color with certainty. That might be a huge endeavor, but if you write fragile UI tests then you'll always be pulling your hair out as the app changes. The app and tests need to be in sync.

Comment: @DanWilson Believe me, I'd restructure the classes if I could, but this is not my website that I'm using ChromeDriver with. I'm just trying to create some sort of automation for this specific website and part of that is pressing the correct things at the correct time. Is there any possible way I could go about this (even if it's impractical) or is my project a lost cause?

Comment: Hmm, not sure. Can you post some example code? Maybe there's a pattern that would make it easier.

Comment: @DanWilson Please see my edits in the OP. Basically, it keeps trying to find an element by the name of "btnCheckAnswer". If it finds that element, it clicks it, moves on to the next page and repeats itself. If it is unable to find the element, the most likely cause is that the process is complete and it figures things out accordingly (not included in the sample)

Comment: Please post some sample HTML with the elements that you are looking for. Make sure that you include the HTML for elements that are the correct color and those that aren't. Is there really no difference in CSS classes on the elements?

Comment: There is a way to do this with JS but I'm hoping that the HTML you post will make it easier to find without having to resort to JS.

Comment: @JeffC Please check the edit in the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your HTML, I'm assuming that all the elements that you want to inspect have the same ID. That's technically against HTML standards but it works in our favor because we can scrape only those elements and then inspect each one to see if it's the right color. Once you have an element, you can get its color using, `.GetCssValue("color")` which will return an RGB value in this format, `"rgba(180, 137, 59, 1)".` You will notice this is RGBA and not RGB. You can read more about RGBA [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba()). You will need to convert your expected RGB values to RGBA but that's pretty straightforward... `rgb(180, 137, 59)` becomes `rgba(180, 137, 59, 1).`

The code below scrapes all the elements with the specified ID, filters it into a new List based on expected color. From there we can loop through the `filtered` collection and write the coordinates of each element using `.Location.[X|Y]`.

```
// IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> unfiltered = Driver.FindElements(By.Id("brdrQuestion.QuestionRenderer.StackPanel.MultiChoiceQuestionViewer.sp.StackPanel.RadioTextRegionViewer1.LayoutRoot.Panel.text.sp.rich.LayoutRoot.TextBlock"));
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> unfiltered = Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("*"));
Console.WriteLine(unfiltered.Count);
List<IWebElement> filtered = unfiltered.Where(f => f.GetCssValue("color") == "rgba(180, 137, 59, 1)").ToList();
Console.WriteLine(filtered.Count);
foreach (IWebElement element in filtered)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.Location.X);
    Console.WriteLine(element.Location.Y);
}
```

Comment: Well not all the elements have the same ID on the web page, they're just very similar. Basically what I'm looking for is something where I can identify elements solely based on their colors and not their IDs, class name, etc.

Comment: OK. You would just need to change the first `.FindElements()` to get all the elements on the page. I was just hoping to narrow that down a little to make it go faster. I've updated the code with this change.